# How to add "-" automatically for mobile number input field while keyup into input field in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a input type text, I want to basically make it for mobile number and add "-" automatically while typing into textbox, for example 999-999-9999, I already tried but its not working. Here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<input (keydown)=onKeydownEvent($event) type="text" maxlength="9" placeholder="mobile number"/>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  show: any;
  name: string = '2019-01-01T23-00-11';
  //name: string = '2019-01-01';
  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onKeydownEvent($event) {
    $(event).val($(event).val().replace(/(\d{3})\-?(\d{3})\-?(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3'))
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is the `maxLength="9"`,  but the example you provide is 10 characters?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/

Answer (score 0):

if it's always the same format, you can always just slice it.

```
var phoneFormatted = phone.slice(0, 3) + "-" + phone.slice(3, 6) + "-" + phone.slice(6);
```

js bin example: https://jsbin.com/zibodosava/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: but how to change it immediately at the time of typing

Answer (score 0):

I Think the simplest solutions is to add [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask)

then you can do

```
<input type='text' mask='(000) 000-0000' >
```

Comment: where to add this I am not getting export const options: Partial<IConfig> | (() => Partial<IConfig>);

Comment: Please follow the documentation here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask